# "Далеко идущие планы" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

"Далеко()идущие планы" — слитно тут или раздельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раздельно. (Словарь-справочник "Слитно или раздельно?" Б.З. Букчина, Л.П.Калуцкая)
Это причастие с зависимым словом-наречием  "далеко".

Answer (score 1):

А на "Грамоте" по орфографическому словарю Лопатина показывается слитное написание. И дело здесь не в словарях. А в том, какая это часть речи. Именно поэтому Екатерина в своем ответе и указывает, что это причастие с зависимым наречием. А если это прилагательное, то писать надо слитно. Проблема в том,  как отличить сложное прилагательное от причастия с зависимым словом. И, как это часто бывает, отличить может только автор. Что он хочет сказать? Далекоидущие т.е. большие, громадные, обширные? - Прилагательное. Пишу слитно. Хочу подчеркнуть именно то, что планы мои **далеко** заходят - напишу раздельно (причастие с зависимым наречием). ТАких случаев очень много. Малоосведомленный - мало осведомленный, давнопрошедший - давно прошедший, долгоиграющий - долго играющий. Все эти написания правомерны.